# Gitlab CI for Angular 2 Project

Tags: angular, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Hi i am trying to setup a ci on gitlab to run a test for every commit and push but i can not setup configuration yml file can any please guide me what i am doing wrong my current yml file is

```
image: node:4.2.2
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
test_app:
  script:
    - npm install  
    - npm test
```

This is giving me error during installation of Phantom.js module so i tried below configuration but is shows invalid syntax.

```
image: node:4.2.2

befor_script:
  - mkdir ~/tmp
  - pushd ~/tmp
  - wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  - tar xf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
  - mv phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 phantomjs
  - ln -s ~/tmp/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
  - phantomjs --version
  - cd ..

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

test_app:
  script:
    - npm install  
    - npm test
```

My Package.Json files is

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Angular2-TypeScript App",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "typescript",
    "webpack"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "start": "gulp serve",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.24",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.28",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.19",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "tslint": "^3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Error i am getting

```
npm info build /builds/test/test/node_modules/rxjs/node_modules/symbol-observable
npm info linkStuff symbol-observable@1.0.4
npm info install symbol-observable@1.0.4
npm info postinstall symbol-observable@1.0.4
npm info build /builds/test/test/node_modules/rxjs
npm info linkStuff rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm info install rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm info postinstall rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm info phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 Failed to exec install script
npm ERR! Linux 4.7.0-coreos-r1
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs-prebuilt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs-prebuilt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm info preuninstall phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13
npm info uninstall phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13
npm info postuninstall phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13
npm info preuninstall karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.2
npm info uninstall karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.2
npm info postuninstall karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /builds/test/test/npm-debug.log
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem, getting the latest nodejs v6 packages solved the problem for me.

Official Ubuntu packages for nodejs is far behind, to install the latest nodejs v6 packages for Ubuntu use below commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the first answer :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge for me was to run e2e tests requiring a real browser running.

Chrome fortunately has `--headless` mode now (and there's even a Debian package) so you don't need PhantomJS any more (reason why its current maintainer has announced plans to discontinue PhantomJS).

**The key is to set up `Xvfb`** before launching Chrome on GitLab CI. For the exact setup code, check [How to run AngularJS end-to-end tests on GitLab CI](https://tekkie.flashbit.net/devops/angular-e2e-tests-on-gitlab-ci).